# Make a live wallpaper

Tags: xubuntu, python3, desktop-background, codecs

I  have a question for you. How can i import a video and insert it as a background. Or let's say a GIF or something like that. I have searched in the ubuntu forums and they propose me to download live wallpaper. I have downloaded it and it's not what i want. i can't insert my own wallpaper and make it live so if someone knows how to do it please help !!!

If someone has a python code or something that works similar to it that may be useful.
And i don't trust the kind of wallpaper apps because it's not coming from a known source.

Comment: from where did you download what? can you add a Link to your question?

Comment: @nobody  there is no link open the web and search live wallpaper for ubuntu, u will find ur link there because there is no link to that. A lot of people opened websites and wrote the same shit over and over again